# Cómo plotear coordenadas bordeando la línea de costa usando la librería ggmap de [R]

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

Qué tal Colegas, tengo esta pequeña situación. Lo que sucede es que quiero plotear zonas en donde se ubican unas especies, para esto estoy utilizando la librería ggplot2, ggmaps, maps, mapdata, raster, plyr, rgdal y maptools; pero a la hora de querer plotear las coordenadas, no encuentro forma de hacerlo de tal manera que la línea se vea pegada a costa... Aquí el ejemplo:

```
x <-data.frame("specie"=c(1:11,1:11), "lat"=c(25.945235,25.945235, 25.945235,25.945235,25.945235,25.945235, 19.744471,18.832071, 19.084574,19.067172, 19.497018,22.216136,18.744251, 21.581057, 20.064758,21.536391,18.85821,18.570462, 18.962724, 21.476433,20.849696,21.170029), "lon"=c(-97.135846, -97.135846,-97.135846, -97.135846, -97.135846, -97.135846, -96.380597, -95.8098,-95.993928,-91.317076,-90.793455,-97.769741, -95.650379,-87.112519,-90.525326,-87.478007,-91.473585,-93.121531,-91.252631, -87.542452,-86.750701,-86.772236))

area <- make_bbox(lon=x$lon, lat=x$lat, f=0.1)

map <- get_map(location=area, maptype="satellite", source="google")

ggmap(map) + geom_path(data = x, mapping = aes(x = x$lon, y = x$lat, group=x$specie), color = x$specie, size=1.2)
```

Con esto obtendo un mapa como este[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la idea es plotear algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es posible sin tener que plotear puntos en toda la costa y luego hacer un geom_lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es lo más parecido que pude lograr utilizando estos paquetes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea consiste en graficar las lineas a partir de las coordenadas de toda la costa. Para eso cree el archivo [linea_costera.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxEwk8NEoCoHX21vYkRRdElJd1U/view?usp=sharing) a partir de los shp de INEGI. Sin embargo por alguna razón no coinciden a la perfección con la imagen del mapa. Se puede jugar con las lineas sumando y restando grados (a las columnas lon y lat) para lograr una mejor coincidencia. Otro tipo de desfase en la imagen es generado para diferenciar las lineas unas de otras. Igual se puede lograr un mejor acomodo de estas sumando y restando grados apropiadamente.

#### Código

Notar que dentro del for se encuentran los puntos de inicio y de termino de cada linea encontrando el punto más cercano a los dados en x. Si se desea graficar otra linea podrían agregarse los punto de inicio y termino.

```
linea<-read.csv("linea_costera.csv")
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(raster)
library(plyr)
library(maptools)
library(dplyr)

x <-data.frame("specie"=c(1:11,1:11), "lat"=c(25.945235,25.945235, `25.945235,25.945235,25.945235,25.945235, 19.744471,18.832071, 19.084574,19.067172, 19.497018,22.216136,18.744251, 21.581057, 20.064758,21.536391,18.85821,18.570462, 18.962724, 21.476433,20.849696,21.170029), "lon"=c(-97.135846, -97.135846,-97.135846, -97.135846, -97.135846, -97.135846, -96.380597, -95.8098,-95.993928,-91.317076,-90.793455,-97.769741, -95.650379,-87.112519,-90.525326,-87.478007,-91.473585,-93.121531,-91.252631, -87.542452,-86.750701,-86.772236))`

linea3<-data.frame()
for(i in 1:11){
  linea2<-mutate(linea,dist1=sqrt((lon-x$lon[i])^2+(lat-x$lat[i])^2),
                 dist2=sqrt((lon-x$lon[i+11])^2+(lat-x$lat[i+11])^2))
  linea2<-linea[which.min(linea2$dist1):which.min(linea2$dist2),]
  linea2$specie<-i
  linea2$lon<-linea2$lon+i*0.1
  linea2$lat<-linea2$lat+i*0.1
  linea3<-rbind(linea3,linea2)
  
}






area <- make_bbox(lon=x$lon, lat=x$lat, f=0.1)

map <- get_map(location=area, maptype="satellite", source="google")

ggmap(map) + geom_path(data = linea3, mapping = aes(x = linea3$lon, y = linea3$lat, group=linea3$specie), color = linea3$specie, size=1.2)
```