# ¿Como generar los datos de coordenada para eventualmente graficar una línea contigua a otra?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

A raiz de [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107890/c%C3%B3mo-plotear-coordenadas-bordeando-la-l%C3%ADnea-de-costa-usando-la-librer%C3%ADa-ggmap-de) pregunta me puse a pensar en el problema que representa poder "dibujar" una línea contigua a otra (no exactamente paralela). Veamos un ejemplo gráfico pequeño. Tenemos por ejemplo esta línea que representamos con las `x`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente una linea es una sucesión de puntos, por lo que nuestra línea podría representarse por el conjunto de las coordenadas de cada punto, por ejemplo podríamos hablar de latitud y longitud, en este ejemplo sería `(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,3), (5,4), (5,5)`

Ahora si quisiéramos generar una segunda línea que vaya acompañando a la primera, la podríamos dibujar muy fácilmente, sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nuestra nueva línea, representada por los `*` sería la que está compuesta por los puntos `(1,3), (2,3), (3,4), (3,5)`. Ahora bien, le pregunta sería: **¿Hay alguna forma matemática o algoritmo para generar los puntos de esta nueva línea?** , es decir poder generar una X cantidad de puntos que tengan una distancia mínima a cualquiera de los puntos de una línea base. Debería ser una solución que soporte casos como esté:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo planteo como un problema agnóstico del lenguaje, pero también me sirven ejemplos de cualquier tipo para estudiar.